# Are loops faster if there are nothing inside them?

Tags: c++, sfml

This may be a silly question, and obviously anything will be faster if nothing is inside a function because it does not need to process anything. However, I was messing around with SFML and decided to try and lag my program with a for loop (since every game loop is 1 frame).

I made a loop that counts to 50,000,000 for every 1 frame, and honestly it still ran at 10 FPS. However, the second I placed a `std::cout << index << std::endl;`, The program would not complete one frame at and counted 1000 every 10ish seconds.

Does having a loop with nothing inside it really make it THAT much faster?

Comment: `std::cout << index << std::endl` is expensive.  Writing to `cout` is bad enough, but adding the `endl` flushes the stream buffer on every call and slows things down still more.

Comment: The compiler is smart.  It said "he isn't doing anything, so why waste time?".  That trick of making a `for` loop run with nothing inside may have worked back, maybe 20 years ago, but in this day and age, writing empty `for` loops like that to slow down the system just won't work with modern-day compilers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - It was much more than 20 years ago. A friend of mine who studied computer science in the early 1980s still vividly remembers the first time he encountered an optimising Pascal compiler - being used then as a teaching aid to introduce students to programming languages - that would completely eliminate a loop with no side-effects. Past colleagues have also informed me that Fortran 66 compilers (dating from the late 1960s) from some vendors routinely eliminated empty loops even when compiling for debugging (i.e. *without* optimisation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your loop has nothing in its body and just counts like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {}
```

Then any decent optimizer will simply remove the entire loop, so not even the count will be performed. The reason is that there is no side-effect, so removing the loop gives an equivalent program.

Even if you were to print the `i` counter variable later on, most optimizers will still be able to remove the loop, because they know `i` will be `50` after the loop.

Therefore, "empty" loops that can be optimized out are infinitely faster.

Comment: See also: [The as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)